# AddClass based on element height

Tags: jquery, height, addclass

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm basically trying to add a class (.scroll) to any .panel-body if it is taller than 320px. Otherwise, don't add the .scroll class to the .panel-body.

What am I doing wrong?

I've supplied a jsfiddle:

```
var maxHeight = 320;
var panelBody = $(this).('.panel-body');
var panelBodyHeight = panelBody.height();

if ( maxHeight < panelBodyHeight ) {
   panelBody.addClass('scroll');
}
else { 
   panelBody.removeClass('scroll');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8sMX4/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in an each loop like this:

```
$('.panel-body').each(function() {
    panel = $(this);
    if (panel.outerHeight() > maxHeight) {
        panel.addClass('scroll');
    } else {
        panel.removeClass('scroll');
    }
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8sMX4/2/)

Or you can use filter:

```
$('.panel-body').filter(function() {
    return $(this).outerHeight() > maxHeight;
}).addClass('scroll');
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8sMX4/9/)

Comment: @JosephSjoblom don't forget to mark answer as a correct one

Answer (score 2):

This is the line where you go wrong:

```
var panelBody = $(this).('.panel-body');
```

It should be:

```
var panelBody = $('.panel-body');
```

Also, you comparison should be `if(panelBodyHeight > maxHeight)`. Thanks @Pete for telling this.

[**Learn more about selecting elements**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) & [**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/8sMX4/3/)

Comment: I had tried that previously. That solution still isn't working for me.

Comment: This is wrong you are also adding the `scroll` class to elements that are not larger than the max-height

Comment: @Pete well, I didn't notice. I've updated it.. Thanks by the way